# debouncing from one stage to another by pressing a button

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

```
    Global Variable:
    bool PressBtn1 = false;
    const int Btn1 = 9;

    void setup()
{
  pinMode(Btn1, INPUT_PULLUP);

}



    void loop()
    {
        CurrentStateOfBtn1 = digitalRead(Btn1);
        if (currentStateOfBtn1 != previousStateOfBtn1)
          {
            if (CurrentStateOfBtn1 == LOW)
            {
              PressBtn1 = true;
            }
            delay(200);
          }
    oldStateConfirm = stateConfirm;
  oldStateInput = stateInput;

    }
```

when I create an IF statement like if a button is pressed to debounce from one number to another or between stages
it has to be written like this

```
if(pressBtn1) 
{
 pressBtn = false  
}
```

IS THERE an easier way to bounce a button, in order to switch from one mode to another?
I cannot understand this piece of code very well ;/

Comment: It doesn't appear you even understand what it means to debounce.  You should understand this first.

Answer (score 0):

By software, here is the easiest way : https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce

It might be useful to manage it by using a function to make it more readable.

you can do it by using a capacitor as well :
https://hackaday.com/2015/12/09/embed-with-elliot-debounce-your-noisy-buttons-part-i/

There is a lot of resources out there, so it's not really a big deal.

Comment: I want a simpler code than those please, to understand or grasp it better please

Comment: you will hardly find something simpler, because it is quite simple already. Especially the 1rst link